# Plot Combined Stacked bar and Bar chart Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine to plot graph in android but there is difficulty with combining stacked bar and bar. I want this type of graph.

[image]

Is it possible to plot like that. If possible then can you give a small footprint.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get to that by building a stacked bar chart only. You don't need to combine a regular bar chart with a stacked bar chart.

There is also the new HEAP type of bar charts which is a stacked bar chart, but with every piece being appended to the previous piece of the bar rather than stacking them one above the other.

Comment: is it possible to add only one lebel like day1 between 2bars day 2 between 2 bar ...